# Error on running open-event-frontend of fossasia

Tags: node-sass

While working on a project , On running command `ember serve` , I got this error

[image: error]

Comment: Please don't attach images of code/errors.

Comment: first, please insert the error as text, not as a link to a picture there's myriads of reasons to do so. Next, please provide enough details to reproduce it (see [mcve]). This way we can probably help you; not likely otherwise. Also, your question has somewhat confusing tag and title, they don't really match with the content, please fix that too